# Is it possible to use same edit text field for two functions

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using edit text field in the map. When  i click on the map i will get the location name in the edit text field. Now i want to use the same edit text field for searching any location i want to go.

I saw one tutorial [here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-google-places-autocomplete-api-as-custom-suggestions-in-android-search-dialog/) for searching location by name in google map. But i want to use same edit text field  for two different actions.

here is an example.

```
case R.id.menu_enableTraffic:
            myMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
            return true;
```

if i click on the enable traffic option means it enables traffic in map.

[image]

Like wise when i click on the search menu option then i want to use same edit text field for searching location. 
 sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible since you are using different buttons for doing two different things. Attach listener to each of the two buttons and get text from the same edittext and use it for search in search click and use it to show traffic when enable traffic option is clicked.

Comment: @Nithi Sethi also one doubt. I saw [this tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-google-places-autocomplete-api-as-custom-suggestions-in-android-search-dialog/). But in this tutorial they clicked search option means then he got search bar. But I want to use already defined text field in the map fragment.

Comment: I don't have much experience working with MapsFragment. Post another question for this or search for it before you post it.